# Handling multiple routes with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Is it possible via react router to handle multiple independent routes in a view?

Like having a component that gets rendered via `/home` and opening in a modal another view via `/contact` and the components rendered by `/home` stays in the background?

I only managed so far having 1 "active" component. As soon as I open up my modal via `/contact` the home component is gone.

Comment: what do you mean by leaving it active? you want both "contact" and "home" components visible on the page?   share your code

Comment: Yes both visible on the same page. But I might have found something. Seems like people use `shouldComponentUpdate` and pass a special prop. Like `is_modal` and based on that you prevent rerendering. But not sure yet if thats the way to go.

Comment: Since you did not provide a code example I created simple code sandbox, check it out in my answer. If you'll provide your own code example I can update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `react-router` renders all matched routes in the order you render them.

So, your desired behavior is default behavior:

```
<main>
  <Route path="/" component={() => <h1>Home</h1>} />
  <Route path="/1" component={() => <h2>Page 1</h2>} />
  <Route path="/2" component={() => <h2>Page 2</h2>} />
</main>
```

On route `"/1"` above code will render components on the first and second routes.

And in order to render only one matched route at a time we need to use `Switch` component:

```
<main>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={() => <h1>Home</h1>} exact />
    <Route path="/1" component={() => <h2>Page 1</h2>} />
    <Route path="/2" component={() => <h2>Page 2</h2>} />
  </Switch>
</main>
```

Now, on route `"/1"` above code will render a component from second route only.
`exact` is used to not match `"/"` all of the time.

Here is the fully working example https://codesandbox.io/s/nnv800pxr4

---

Also, there is another way to achieve such behavior - nested routes. Just render something else beyond child routes and it will be rendered all the time any of child routes are matched:

```
// somewhere in routes
<Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent} />

// HomeComponent content
<div>
  <h1>Some content<h1>
  <h2>Rendered every time HomeComponent are rendered!</h2>
  <Switch>
    {/* some child routes */}
    <Routes path="/contacts" component={ContactModal} />
    {/* some child routes */}
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Note, that currently `react-router@4` [lacks good nested routes API](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4940). IMO, in `react-router@3` such things were much easier to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Yeah thats based on how the regex of react router works. But this is only a solution if the paths consist of each other. This won't work if you have 2 routes with `/home` and `/contact`. 

Here is an example how someone solved a similar issue on another library https://github.com/davidmfoley/react-router-modal/issues/24#issuecomment-407919439 Similar to this example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery 
I was just hoping that there is a simpler solution :-/

Comment: Nesting was my original solution. The problem with nesting is that your DOM can't be separated. Think about the following: you want a div for a modal that is position absolute beyond everything. As soon as you nest this div inside you parent routes you have a issue. 
Yeah you are right. `react-router@3` had some advantages there

Comment: With react's portals root div of the modal can totally be separated from the route. Only modal 'triggerer' element would be coupled, such as link/open button, right?

Comment: Oh. I never heard of react portals. That sounds promising!

Comment: you are brilliant @amankkg :) you basically solved with the portals hint an older issue of mine too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684048/react-router-list-and-detail-route-at-the-same-time